# Spring Boot - Mark API as Yet to implement

Tags: spring-boot, swagger, swagger-ui

I am using Spring boot for exposing REST APIs and using springdoc-openapi-ui for swagger document the APIs.
Couple of APIs that are not yet implemented. But QA's are creating bugs for those apis. Is there a way I can mark certain APIs as not yet implemented in Spring Boot?

Comment: Do you mean hide them from Swagger UI?

Comment: Nope. I need to show the swagger document but need to mark it as Not yet implemented as discussed [here](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues/1706).